# Can't create file outside of root directory

Tags: php, server

I have a server hosted by Altervista. Now since I don't want a file that I manage to be accessed by visitors, I wanted to put it outside of the root directory. I thought `/var/www/` would work but it doesn't, or maybe I can't access at it.

Do you know how I can avoid users to access this file?

Comment: So you don't need to access the file later? Or will you? Because if not, you can change the file permissions to something different than 0644 and that might work for you. More info about PHP `chmod()` in http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php ... maybe 0640?

Comment: I need to access the file later for reading

Comment: Using the browser or inside your control panel? Changing the file permissions to 0640 won't allow site visitors to access the file, but you can still do it as the owner.

Comment: "I thought /var/www/ would work" — Probably.  "but it doesn't, or maybe I can't access at it" — What did you do? How did you create the file? How did you try to access it? What happened?

Comment: So, I have a php script in mydomain.altervista.org/myscript.php in this script I manage a text file which I don't want people to access it

Comment: I also changed permissions to 0640 but I still can access it even if I'm visitor :/

Comment: How about 0700? (Going extreme here)

Comment: "0640 but I still can access it even if I'm visitor" — So, presumbably, your webroot is `/var/www/` rather than `/var/www/htdocs` … so put the file somewhere else that *isn't* in the web root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could protect files in a subdirectory of your `/var/www` with a password via .htaccess and .htpasswd files in the subdirectory  (procedure described here https://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess, e.g.).